# Python cannot get all information from xml document

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm using the 'lxml' library with python and its returning to me all the text within 1 set of tags but not for the other set of tags. For example, my xml document looks something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<TEXT><![CDATA[
Record date: 2067-05-03

   55 yo woman who presents for f/u 

]]></TEXT>
<TAGS>
<DATE id="P0" start="16" end="26" text="2067-05-03" comment="" />
<AGE id="P1" start="50" end="52" text="55" comment="" />

</TAGS>
```

My problem is that its correctly retrieving all the text between the <TEXT> and </TEXT> but it is not correctly retrieving the text between <TAGS> and </TAGS>, it is only saying that there is one '\n' when I check for the text, for context, here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r'myXMLDocument.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for c in root:
    print(c.text)
```

Additionally,

```
>>> root[1].text
'\n'
```

Is there a way I can get it to give me back

```
<DATE id="P0" start="16" end="26" text="2067-05-03" comment="" />
<AGE id="P1" start="50" end="52" text="55" comment="" />
```

or would this not be possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with xml, you are probably using a library which support xpath, like this:

```
from lxml import etree

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
<TEXT><![CDATA[
Record date: 2067-05-03

   55 yo woman who presents for f/u 

]]></TEXT>
<TAGS>
<DATE id="P0" start="16" end="26" text="2067-05-03" comment="" />
<AGE id="P1" start="50" end="52" text="55" comment="" />
</TAGS>
</root>""" #note that you need your xml to be wrapped in a root node in order to be well formed

doc = etree.XML(data.encode())
for date in doc.xpath('//DATE'):
    print(etree.tostring(date).decode())
for age in doc.xpath('//AGE'):
    print(etree.tostring(age).decode())
```

Output:

```
<DATE id="P0" start="16" end="26" text="2067-05-03" comment=""/>

<AGE id="P1" start="50" end="52" text="55" comment=""/>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused by the 'data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' line, when is this statement meant to be closed?

Comment: It doesn't. See, for example, https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import  utils, SimplifiedDoc
xml = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<TEXT><![CDATA[
Record date: 2067-05-03

   55 yo woman who presents for f/u 

]]></TEXT>
<TAGS>
<DATE id="P0" start="16" end="26" text="2067-05-03" comment="" />
<AGE id="P1" start="50" end="52" text="55" comment="" />

</TAGS>
'''

doc  = SimplifiedDoc(xml)

print (doc.TAGS.html)
# Result:
'''
<DATE id="P0" start="16" end="26" text="2067-05-03" comment="" />
<AGE id="P1" start="50" end="52" text="55" comment="" />
'''

print (doc.select('TAGS').children)
# Result:
'''
[{'tag': 'DATE', 'id': 'P0', 'start': '16', 'end': '26', 'text': '2067-05-03', 'comment': '', 'html': ''}, {'tag': 'AGE', 'id': 'P1', 'start': '50', 'end': '52', 'text': '55', 'comment': '', 'html': ''}]
'''

print (doc.select('TAGS>DATE'))
# Result:
'''
{'tag': 'DATE', 'id': 'P0', 'start': '16', 'end': '26', 'text': '2067-05-03', 'comment': '', 'html': ''}
'''
```